# Cannot call delete on repository inside a runnable

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a command line runner that will execute a runnable class `MyRunnable` as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDao;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        taskExecutor.execute(new MyRunnable(myDao))
    }

}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    
    private MyDAO myDao;

    public MyRunnable(MyDAO myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        myDao.deleteAll();
    }

}

@Repository
public interface MyDAO extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {}
```

The `TaskExecutor` is a managed bean.  Since `MyRunnable` is not spring-managed, I passed in the `MyDAO` to its constructor so I can call later.  However, when I call the `deleteAll()`, I got the following error:

```
No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException...
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved by annotating the method `deleteAll` with `@Transactional`

Comment: There probably is something wrong with your configuration as `By default, methods inherited from CrudRepository inherit the transactional configuration from SimpleJpaRepository`. Did you name your PlatformTransactionManager bean as `transactionManager`?